# A ball is a subset of another ball

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we know that $0 < S_1 \leq S_2$ and that $a$ belongs to the set $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How would you show that $B(a,S_1)$ is a subset of $B(a,S_2)$?

Comment: Just recall yourself the definition of $B(a,S)$.

Comment: Are $S_1$ and $S_2$ positive real numbers here?

Comment: Where exactly do you stuck?

Comment: Yes, S1 and S2 are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the definition of $B(a,S1)$ as all points within $S1$ of $a$. If a point is within $S1$, it is within $S2$

Answer (score 0):

$$x\in B(a,r)\iff |x-a|<r$$

Use the fact that $|x-a|<S_1$ then $|x-a|<S_2$.