# An open ball contained within another open ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose $$B(a, r_1)\subset B(b, r_2).$$ How do I prove that $$r_1\leq r_2\;\;?$$ It seems extremely obvious but I can't efficiently construct a concise and rigorous proof.

My attempt so far involves circular reasoning. I tried to prove by contradiction.
Suppose $r>s$, then $$B(a,r_1)\cap B(b,r_2)\subset B(b,r_2).$$
By the property of proper sets, $\exists p\in B(a,r_1)$ such that $p\notin B(b,r_2)$. But by definition, $B(a,r_1)\subset B(b,r_2)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hello, it seems like this has answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337455/a-ball-is-a-subset-of-another-ball does those answers sort-of help? If not, would you be able to further edit your post to show an attempt at your proof? Then, the community has something to work on to help you better understand your current issue with this problem

Comment: This is not true in a "discrete" metric space, where $d(x,y)=1$ when $x \neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0.$ You need some assumption about the metric. [why not true in discrete: $B(v,1/2) \subset B(v,1/3)$ yet $1/2$ is greater than $1/3.$ Both balls contain only $v.$]

Answer (score 3):

In case $a\ne b$, then the statement is false. I will give a couterexample but will keep the case $a=b=v$ below in case someone in the future needed it.

Let $X=\{0,3,6\}$ be endowed with the regular distance on $\mathbb{R}$

then,
$$B(0,5)=\{0,3\} \text{ and } B(3,4)=\{0,3,6\}$$
$$\Rightarrow B(0,5)\subset B(3,4)\text{ but } 5\not\le 4$$

I am assuming by $\subset$ means a strict subset or else the property is not true.

If
$$B(v,r_1)\subset B(v,r_2)$$
Then there is an $x\in B(v,r_2)$ such that $x\notin B(v,r_1)$
$$\Rightarrow r_1\le d(v,x)\text{ and } d(v,x)<r_2$$
$$\Rightarrow r_1<r_2$$

Comment: This proves the other implication.

Comment: @jjagmath. True ^^, I fixed it , thank you!

Comment: Sorry I edited my question, the two open balls are centered at different points. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user9817801 updated, hope this helps.